# Quelle serait une meilleure façon (avec d’autres termes) de formuler la phrase ci-après?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation, reformulation

Christine Morency est un mélange entre Lise Dion et Jean-Marc-Parent.

En parlant d’humoristes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Quelques possibilités*

- Christine Morency tient de Lise Dion et de Jean-Marc-Parent. (*factuel, pas imagé*)
- Christine Morency est une humoriste hybride chez laquelle on retrouve Lise Dion et Jean-Marc-Parent. (*plutôt métaphorique mais sans connotations*)
- L'art de Christine Morency est un croisement entre celui de Lise Dion et celui de Jean-Marc-Parent. (*métaphorique, sans connotations*)
- Lorsqu'on entend Christine Morency on croirait entendre  Lise Dion et Jean-Marc-Parent. (*factuel, tend à avoir des connotations négatives*)
- Qui dit Christine Morency dit Lise Dion et Jean-Marc-Parent. (*factuel, connotations négatives possibles mais  atténuées*)
- (En tant qu'humoriste) Christine Morency s'inspire de Lise Dion et de Jean-Marc-Parent. (*mention explicite d'une origine, ce qui rend la formulation légèrement différente*)
- L'art humoristique de Christine Morency s'inspire de ceux de Lise Dion et de Jean-Marc-Parent.  (*mention explicite d'une origine, ce qui rend la formulation légèrement différente*)
- Christine Morency sur scène c'est  Lise Dion et Jean-Marc-Parent tout crachés. (attention, plutôt familier)